# Amazon SQS temporary queues (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to create a PHP implementation using Amazon SQS with PHP SDK V3. It would be really usefull for some tasks to use disposable/temporary queues.

Per reading Amazon docs I found it's possible in Java SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-temporary-queues.html).

I try to use the "#" sintax, but with no success. Also passing it as an Attribute, also nothing.

Basic code:

```
$result = $client -> createQueue(
    array(
            'QueueName' =>          'Test',
            'Attributes' => array(
                                    'VirtualQueueName' => 'temp'
            )
    )
);
```

Does anyone knows the same docs in PHP or a way for doing this without Java SDK?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't actually creating temporary queues. It is creating a single queue, and adds a 'virtual queue identifier' as an attribute to the message. Then, a process reads messages from the queue and forwards it to virtual queues.

Looks rather complex since you need to run code from Github to implement this virtual capability.

Instead, I would recommend you just **create a normal queue with a unique name and then delete it when it is not required**.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this "sqs temporary queue" capability is actually provided by a Java library, implementing the sqs client interface in a smart way, in memory. However, documentation does not really highlight explicitly that this is a custom Java implementation.

See https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-temporary-queues-client